# poetry pyviz pandas version conflict

Tags: python-poetry, pyviz

What does this enigmatic message says and how should I solve it?

```
> poetry add pyviz

Because no versions of pyviz match >0.10.3,<0.11.0
 and pyviz (0.10.3) depends on pandas (>=0.23.4,<0.25.0), pyviz (>=0.10.3,<0.11.0) requires pandas (>=0.23.4,<0.25.0).
So, because poe depends on both pandas (^2.1.2) and pyviz (^0.10.3), version solving failed.
```

I looked at pyviz and didn't find a constrain <0.25.0 in it's requirements.txt file. Moreover, how can I ignore the issue and just let it install the damm thing?